# Update all models at once in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I am trying to update position field for all objects in specific order at once in Django (python).

This is how I've done it now, but the problem is that it makes loads of queries.

```
    servers = frontend_models.Server.objects.all().order_by('-vote_count')

    i = 1
    for server in servers:
        server.last_rank = i
        server.save()
        i += 1
```

Is there a way to update with

```
Model.objects.all().order_by('some_field').update(position=some_number_that_changes_for each_object)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You want to increment the passed number for each object?

Comment: django query api don't has [windows functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) (I think). You should execute [custom sql directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) if your RDBMS has this feature.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions) expression from `django.db.models` to do the same:

```
Model.objects.all().order_by('some_field').update(position=F(some_field)+1)
```

which will generate a single SQL query to update all of the column values, so it is efficient to the database too.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, as F() can only calculate based on the value of a field in the same row, rather than incrementing across rows as he wants.

Comment: For the specific stated problem, it can be refactored to work on the same row too; no?

Comment: this could work only if i could use previous row with F(same_field_of_previous_row) + 1

Comment: "Instances of F() act as a reference to a model field within a query. These references can then be used in query filters to compare the values of two different fields on the same model instance."  Hence this wouldn't accomplish what the OP needs to do.

Comment: Also we should have some quotes inside that F('some_field') just to be really explicit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Django's object-relational mapping system doesn't provide a way to express this update operation. But if you know how to express it in SQL, then you can run it via a [custom SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''UPDATE myapp_server ...''')
```

Different database engines express this operation in different ways. In MySQL you'd run this query:

```
SET @rownum=0;
UPDATE myapp_server A,
       (SELECT id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
        FROM myapp_server
        ORDER BY vote_count DESCENDING) B
SET A.rank = B.rank
WHERE A.id = B.id
```

In PostgreSQL I think you'd use

```
UPDATE myapp_server A,
       (SELECT id, rownumber() AS rank
        OVER (ORDER BY vote_count DESCENDING)
        FROM myapp_server) B
SET A.rank = B.rank
WHERE A.id = B.id
```

(but that's untested, so beware!).